# Can't unstalled vue.js using 'sudo npm uninstall @vue/cli -g'

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs2, npm-install, uninstallation

I want to unistall vue.js on my machine. hence I used following commond to uninstall vue.js on my 'Ubuntu' OS

```
sudo npm uninstall @vue/cli -g
```

i'm checking uninstallation using '`vue --version`' commond

but still showing a version of vue like as below

```
2.9.6
```

how i unistalled currently installing vue packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to uninstall  using the steps below

step 1 -> using '`which vue`' commond to saw where vue was installed.

ex -:

```
kaw@kaw-HP-Notebook:~/script1/Hutch OPS/vue1$ which vue
/usr/local/bin/vue
```

step 2-: go to vue installed location

```
ex -: cd /usr/local/bin
```

step 3-: Now use following commands to uninstalled the vue

```
sudo rm -rf vue
sudo rm -rf vue-init
sudo rm -rf vue-list
```

[image]